# Memory leak in fortran 2003

Tags: oop, memory-leaks, fortran

I have a memory leak when using a "constructor"(which is just a static function) to create an initialize a derived type object.

I have two subroutines that seem to be equivalent, but one of them has a memory leak (mult_leak), while the other hasn't (mult_noleak).

I don't understand which is the difference.

```
program main
    use lala
    type(mytype) :: mt1, mt2, mt3
    integer :: i
    real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: dat
    allocate(dat(1000, 1000))
    dat = 1.5

    do i=1,10000000
        mt1 = creador(dat)
        mt2 = creador(dat)
        mt3 = mult_leak(mt1, mt2)
        if(modulo(i,1000)==0) then
            print*, i, mt3%dat(1,1)
        endif       
    end do

end program

module lala

    type mytype

        integer :: nx, ny
        real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: dat

        contains
            private
            procedure :: init
    end type

interface creador
    procedure p_creador
end interface

contains
    subroutine init(this, dat)
        class(mytype) :: this
        real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: dat
        integer, dimension(2) :: s
        s = shape(dat)
        this%nx = s(1)
        this%ny = s(2)

        allocate(this%dat, source=dat)
    end subroutine

    function p_creador(dat) result(res)
        type(mytype), allocatable :: res
        real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: dat

        allocate(res)
        call res%init(dat)
    end function

    function mult_noleak(cf1, cf2) result(cfres)
        class(mytype), intent(in) :: cf1, cf2
        class(mytype), allocatable :: cfres

        real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: aux

        allocate(cfres)

        aux=cf1%dat * cf2%dat

        call cfres%init(aux)

    end function

    function mult_leak(cf1, cf2) result(cfres)
        class(mytype), intent(in) :: cf1, cf2
        class(mytype), allocatable :: cfres

        real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: aux

        aux=cf1%dat * cf2%dat
        cfres = creador(aux)

    end function
end module
```

Comment: I tried changing the mt3 assignment in the main loop to be the return value of mult_noleak and valgrind is still reporting a memory leak for me

Comment: The code you posted seems to be not the code showing the error.  First, the module `lala` must occur before the main program.  Second, what is init_2?

Comment: Difficult to be totally sure as I can't test for the reason given by evets, but it looks to me like you are using Shape on an unallocated allocatable array, This is in init when called from p_creador. This is not allowed by the standard and so As all bets are off. Also allocate(this%dat, source=dat) with unallocated dat looks strange to me - in fact quite how the various entities called dat are handled is a bit strange.

Comment: @evets init_2 was another initialization subroutine but it is irrelevant to reproduce the bug. Y have already edited the question.

Comment: @IanBush how do you suggest to handle the dat entities in this initialization?

Comment: To be honest I can't work out what you are trying to achieve, so I can't help, sorry. Is there any relationship between the dat in the main program and that in p_creador?

Comment: @IanBush sorry. I copied and pasted the code incorrectly. Now the code is exactly how i reproduce the problem. 

mt1 = creador(dat)
mt2 = creador(dat)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the leak disappears when I change the "cfres" definition in "mult_leak" subroutine.

```
function mult_leak(cf1, cf2) result(cfres)
        class(mytype), intent(in) :: cf1, cf2
        !class(mytype), allocatable :: cfres
        type(mytype), allocatable :: cfres

        real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: aux

        aux=cf1%dat * cf2%dat
        cfres = creador(aux)

end function
```

It seems that the problem is the assignment of the constructor to a polymorphic entity.